# Python: Find date of monday of a given calender week in a given year

Tags: python, calendar, week-number

I have a questions about Python.

My goal is the following: Let a year and a calender week be given. Then I want to find the calender date of the Monday of this calender week.

I want to use the calender week standard ISO 8601, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Numbering

I have written the following code:

```
def calWeekMonday(year,calWeek):
    firstDayOfYear = int(dt.date(year,1,1).strftime("%w")) # first day of year as a number
    if calWeek > 53:
        return "There exists no calender week greater than 53."
    elif calWeek == 53 and firstDayOfYear != 4:
        # a year has 53 calender weeks if and only if it starts with Thursday
        return "There is no calender week 53 in this year."
    else:
        if firstDayOfYear < 4: # then Jan 1st is in week 1 of the new year
            mondayWeek1 = dt.date(year, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=-(firstDayOfYear - 1))
        else:  # then Jan 1st is in last week of old year
            mondayWeek1 = dt.date(year, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=7 - firstDayOfYear + 1)
        # calculate monday of calWeek
        wantedMonday = mondayWeek1 + dt.timedelta(weeks=(calWeek - 1))
    return wantedMonday
```

I have tested some examples and they work, but I am worried that I haven't considered all special cases (there are a loooot of them). Maybe someone can help me with the following questions:

Is there any way to make sure that my code works for ALL special cases?
Does anyone see a mistake in my code?
Does anyone have any improvements?
Is there a faster/easier way to do it, for example, is there any package which might help me (I tried to find something, but I wasn't successfull).

I am happy about any help and want to say thank you in advance!

Comment: sorry, forgot the following line at the beginning:
`import datetime as dt`

Comment: if you want `ISO 8601` then you should use  `.isoweekday()` instead of `int( .strftime("%w"))` because `%w` gives `0` for `Sunday` but it should be `7` (and `.isoweekday()` gives `7`)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your function works for most inputs. Of course, if you are handling week 53+, then do you want to handle non-positive inputs? If you give a zero/negative week-number then the function gives a date from a different year, is this what you want?

Negative years give an error (obviously), do you want to handle that?

Finally, you haven't considered leap years in your '53-week years must start on Thursday' rule (2020 was 53-week but started on Wednesday)